# VB6 - Set Debug Mode via Registry?

Tags: debugging, logging, vb6

I have a VB6 application that I'm trying to make log out differently.  What I have is a flag in the registry (existing) which states if the application is set to Debug mode so that it would log out.

Within my code I then have lots of if statements checking if this is true.  This means that there is a lot of processing time checking if a statement is true, which maybe not much really but as it does it so often it's an overhead I would like to reduce.

The code is full of statements like this

```
If isDebug = True Then
    LogMessage("Log what is happening")
End If
```

So what I'm looking for is a better way to do this.  I know I can set a debug mode within Project Properties -> Make, but this needs to be set prior to building the .exe and I want to be able to set this in production via the registry key.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to avoid conditional statement (`if`)? Of course, there is none.

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov There is `Select...Case`

Comment: You can change your first line to `If isDebug Then` to make it more succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a command line argument to set debug mode. I used to do this.

```
Dim sCommandLine() As String
sCommandLine = Split(Command$)
For I = 0 To UBound(sCommandLine)
    ' do something with each arg
Next I
```

You can also persist command line args inside the IDE, so you always have them when debugging. When running outside of the IDE, make a shortcut to the compiled application with the arguments in it.

Answer (score 1):

I do something almost identical to what you have in mind in a lot of my code.  Add this:

```
Sub LogDebug(ByVal strMsg As String)
    If (isDebug) Then
        LogMessage(strMsg)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then just call `LogDebug` in your main program body, or call `LogMessage` directly if it's something you always want to log, regardless of the debug flag.

I'm assuming `isDebug` is a boolean here.  If it's a function call, you should just create a global flag that you set at the beginning of the code, and check that instead of looking at the registry over and over.  I don't think checking a boolean is that much of a processing load, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to call a function if a runtime flag is set. The only thing I can see that could be faster is:

```
If isDebug Then
    LogMessage("Log what is happening")
End If
```

But I doubt that either would be the cause of performance problems. Most logging frameworks promote code like that and even put the flag/log level as a parameter to the function. Just be sure that you don't have other places where you needlessly compute a log message outside of the conditional statement.

You might evaluate why you need logging and if the logs produced are effective for that purpose.

If you are looking for a problem that can be trapped using VB error handling, consider a good error handling library like [HuntERR31](http://www.findthatzipfile.com/search-26883831-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-8099.zip.htm). With it you can choose to log only errors instead of the debug message you are now doing. Even if you don't use the library, the docs have a very good description of error handling in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer still:

Read your registry flag into your app so that it's a session based thing (i.e. when you close and restart the app the flag will be checked again - there's no point in checking the registry with every single test).

Then (as per Tom's post) assign the value to a global variable and test that - far faster than a function.

To speed up logging you may want to consider dimensioning a string buffer in your app and, once it has reached a specific size, fire it into your log file.  Obviously there are certain problems with this approach, namely the volatility of the memory, but if you want performance over disk access I would recommend such an approach.

This would, of course, be a lot easier if you could show us some code for your logging process etc.